# Simple xsl:key doesn't match

Tags: xslt, xpath, xhtml, saxon-js

Can't figure out the correct parameters for this xsl:key example to work. What I want is to output the same xhtml with rate/name fields changed based on the data in root.xml.

**XHMTL (main input)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>PZBank</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width:100%">
       <tr>
          <th align="left">Product #1</th>
          <th align="left">Product #2</th>
          <th align="left">Product #3</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td name="name0">Whiz-bang</td>
          <td name="name1">Ulitmate</td>
          <td name="name2">Killer</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td name="rate0">2.09</td>
          <td name="rate1">1.99</td>
          <td name="rate2">3.19</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**XML - root.xml**

```
<root>
  <dbu>
    <product ord="0">
      <name>Amazing</name>
      <rate>4.5</rate>
    </product>
  </dbu>
  <dbu>
    <product ord="1">
      <name>Incredible</name>
      <rate>6.6</rate>
    </product>
  </dbu>
</root>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" include-content-type="no"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:variable name="rooter" select="document('root.xml')"/>

  <xsl:key name="krate" match="product/rate" use="/root/dbu/product[@ord]"/>

  <xsl:key name="kname" match="name" use="@ord"/>

  <xsl:template match="td[starts-with(@name,'rate')]/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="ordv" select="substring-after(../@name,'rate')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$rooter">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('krate',$ordv)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="td[starts-with(@name,'name')]/text()">
    {key('kname', substring-after(../@name, 'name'), $rooter)}
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is happening is the name/rate fields are blank in the output so obviously the xsl:key calls are incorrect. I have even tried 2 approaches: krate and kname but no luck. I have also tried a number of different @ord xpath strings on the xsl:key.

The root.xml is just a test version. In production it will be much more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your second approach for both. So try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" include-content-type="no"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  
  <xsl:variable name="rooter" select="document('root.xml')"/>
  <xsl:key name="kord" match="/root/dbu/product" use="@ord"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="td[starts-with(@name,'rate')]/text()">{key('kord', substring-after(../@name, 'rate'), $rooter)/rate}</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="td[starts-with(@name,'name')]/text()">{key('kord', substring-after(../@name, 'name'), $rooter)/name}</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `xsl:strip-space` removes the empty lines between the elements.
If you really need the `xsl:for-each` for `rate`, it could look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="td[starts-with(@name,'rate')]/text()">
  <xsl:variable name="ordv" select="substring-after(../@name,'rate')"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$rooter">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('kord',$ordv)/rate"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>PZBank</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th align="left">Product #1</th>
                <th align="left">Product #2</th>
                <th align="left">Product #3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td name="name0">Amazing</td>
                <td name="name1">Incredible</td>
                <td name="name2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td name="rate0">4.5</td>
                <td name="rate1">6.6</td>
                <td name="rate2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```